# Vaadin Flow with Spring-Boot, Gui issues,

Tags: spring-boot, maven, vaadin

My application has been built without errors, but when I open it in browser the views are destroyed/ malformed. I've no idea why or what has been going wrong.

Building run without errors. TechStack is Spring-Boot/ Jpa / Vaadin Flow 14.
Running it with Spring-Boot works.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.spring.app.packteam</groupId>
<artifactId>packteam</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Packteam</name>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

    <!--Drivers -->
    <drivers.dir>${project.basedir}/drivers</drivers.dir>
    <drivers.downloader.phase>pre-integration-test</drivers.downloader.phase>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <vaadin.version>14.1.19</vaadin.version>

    <!-- Overrides the old version specified by the Spring Boot parent -->
    <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <frontend.maven.plugin.version>1.8</frontend.maven.plugin.version>
    <maven.jar.plugin.version>3.2.0</maven.jar.plugin.version>
    <maven.resources.plugin.version>3.1.0</maven.resources.plugin.version>
    <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
    <eirslett.version>1.8.0</eirslett.version>



    <!-- Frontend -->
    <node.version>v10.16.3</node.version>
    <!-- <yarn.version>v1.16.0</yarn.version> -->
    <!-- <buildtools.directory>build-tools</buildtools.directory> -->



</properties>

<repositories>

    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
    <repository>
        <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Spring-Boot -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Vaadin -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility 
                mode -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtgraphicscharts</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Datenbank -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testtools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <!-- <exclusions> -->
        <!-- <exclusion> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId> -->
        <!-- </exclusion> -->
        <!-- </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed 
                the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout. -->
            <configuration>
                <wait>500</wait>
                <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in package.json 
            and main.js files. It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <jvmArguments>-Dvaadin.productionMode</jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                        <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <!-- Pass location of downloaded webdrivers to the tests -->
                            <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>true
                        </onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>
                        <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                            ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver
                        </rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                        <downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                            ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver_zips
                        </downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                        <customRepositoryMap>
                            ${project.basedir}/drivers.xml
                        </customRepositoryMap>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <!-- use phase "none" to skip download step -->
                            <phase>${drivers.downloader.phase}</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>selenium</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "malformed".  I assume, your stylesheets are not loading? Please make sure to run the "prepare-frontend" tasks and/or also the "build-frontend" with production mode (depending on how you run/test it)

Comment: you may also check which stylesheets are loaded by the browser by opening the developer console in your browser and go to the network tab. If any stylesheet cannot be resolved, this may be your problem. (Which might be resolved by the aforementioned buildsteps)

Comment: Do you have any errors in server/browser console? Could you also elaborate what do you mean by malformed? It's hard to help without further details :/